# Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i (201NGW) disconnecting periodically (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

Just got a new Razer Blade Stealth 13 (Late 2019) and dual booted Ubuntu 20.04 on it.
Sometimes when using WiFi heavily (e.g. video calling or gaming) the WiFi will cut out, about once every 45 minutes, and I have to turn WiFi off and back on. I haven't been able to trigger it on purpose, but it's consistent enough to be annoying.

Any ideas on what I can try?

`sudo lshw -C network` outputs:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 30
       serial: 98:af:65:5e:eb:5b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-33-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 ip=192.168.1.243 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:6053174000-6053177fff
```

`iwconfig` outputs:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"WalkingNet5.0"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: 48:5D:36:52:AE:F4   
          Bit Rate=292.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1163   Missed beacon:0
```

Update months later: this still happens consistently on my home network (Verizon) and never on many other networks. No one else on my home network has noticed this happening to them, and the fix is to toggle my own wifi on and off, so I don't think this is a network issue.

Comment: In terminal try `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf && systemctl restart network-manager.service`

Comment: Ok tried that. I guess I'll wait a few days and see if it happens, and let you know. Thanks!
Are there any side effects of turning wifi power management off? e.g. it does seem reasonable to have wifi off while the computer is asleep.

Comment: It's still happening (after restarting the whole computer too)

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well. I'm able to reproduce this bug by loading my music library from Google Play Music with [docker-gmusicapi](https://github.com/robertbeal/docker-gmusicapi). Maybe it is related to long running connections. I'm sure there must be a Launchpad bug for this but I wasn't able to find one. Please mention me if you find something.